# Purposely trying to break Python class inheritance, don't understand why it breaks this way

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

I'm exploring the limits of Python class inheritance, so I wrote a small test to see how much I can get away with - redeclaring properties and overriding functions.

```
class A:
    val : int = 3
    def foo(x: int):
        print(x)

class B(A):
    val : str = 'python'
    def foo(x: str):
        print(x)

a = A()
b = B()
a.foo(5)
b.foo('test')
print(a.val)
print(b.val)
```

The resulting output is surprising. I would have expected some kind of exception for redeclaring the property, but instead I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Development\Playground\hello.py", line 12, in <module>
    a.foo(5)
TypeError: A.foo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I don't see how it interpreting that I am providing two positional arguments for `a.foo(5)`. Granted I am trying to break it but I still want to understand.

Comment: What do you think `foo()` is in both classes? Do you think its a method of some sort?

Comment: @GoldenJoe isnt the problem that by doing this, you are passing to the program `(a, 5)` (a => self) ? Try calling `A.foo(5)`

Comment: You might want to familiarize yourself with the basics before trying to test the limits - `name: type` is just a type *hint* that python explicitly does not enforce, and methods need an explicit parameter (commonly `self`) to receive the instance.

Comment: By the way, type hint is only a hint. It doesn't require you to pass in a string or anything else

Answer (score 1):

You need a self parameter for instance methods.

```
class A:
    val : int = 3
    def foo(self, x: int):
        print(x)

class B(A):
    val : str = 'python'
    def foo(self, x: str):
        print(x)

a = A()
b = B()
a.foo(5)
b.foo('test')
print(a.val)
print(b.val)
```

Output:

```
5
test
3
python
```

Comment: Ok, so this "fixed" the problem with the code, but how do you know that this is what the OP wants?

Comment: What do you mean by that? If OP wants a true overload he could go for metaclasses, this fixed the problem of missing self parameter.

Comment: `this fixed the problem of missing self parameter` if that was the problem. There are always, at least, two ways of fixing a problem. You could have suggested sth like: `a.foo()`.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I know you are not looking for a fix, but an idea about what the interpreter is doing I can walk you through one line of your code:

`a.foo(5)`

This line is just a *nice* way for us programmers to express the idea of calling a method (`foo`) on an instance (`a`). This is syntactic sugar and I like to think of the interpreter transforming that text to this text:

`A.foo(a, 5)`

and then compiling that. Now you can see, when you compare that line of code to the method that you defined: `def foo(x: int):` that the interpreter is going to say that the method takes one positional argument (`x`) but *you* are giving it two: `(a, 5)`

Comment: I follow your thinking, but is this supported anywhere? If the interpreter is transforming that line to `A.foo(a, 5)`, why only throw this error when `class B` exists?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with class B.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is produced because self was automatically passed since it's a function of a class so your functions have to take self as their first argument

```
class A:
    val : int = 3
    def foo(self, x: int):
        print(x)

class B(A):
    val : str = 'python'
    def foo(self, x: str):
        print(x)
```

Comment: You seem to have reproduced part of the code that the OP posted. I don't see how that helps the OP.

Comment: I forgot to actually include the change. now fixed

Comment: I see you have updated your post to include a `self` parameter. So now you have copied the code suggested by `Fed_Dragon`. How do you know that this is what the OP wants?

Comment: @quamrana Would you please inform me about what the OP wants? I really don't understand at this point.

Comment: I would just love to inform you about what the OP wants. (I've just been trying to enumerate the possible "solutions" and I'm up to 4 so far) However, there seems to be nothing from the OP apart from the original post.

Comment: If it isn't I am sure Fed_Dragon is able to tell that himself but than Fed_Dragon has further explain what Hesse wants

Comment: Sorry, I'm not looking for a fix. I'm just curious what the interpreter is doing.